# Angular call parent function with arguments from directive two levels deep

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem in Angular where I have a function declared in my controller and I want a directive to be able to call this function. I use the `&` in the directives scope to reference the parent function.

The problem occurs when there is another directive inside the first one and the inner directive also references this function in the controller.

The function can be called from within the first directive and the second directive (if the function has no arguments). The function can be called from the first directive and NOT from the second directive (if the function has arguments).

This plnkr shows it in action:

https://plnkr.co/edit/8E5oNvWcF0QQWL7pmxrD?p=preview

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<directive-two increment="increment()" add="add({amount : amount})"></directive-two>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/WvVcNIOJ8zKvFmchOQ5R?p=preview

Comment: It works! I don't get why you have to declare the arguments in JSON when passing a reference to the function further down the scope (from directiveOne into directiveTwo). It seems so verbose and if you had a method with more than two arguments the HTML would get really messy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing functions you have multiple options, i recommend you to check this article http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters

I updated your plnkr with my favourite option, storing a function reference and invoking it, first you must reference  the function on the directive without adding the parenthesis after the function name as shown next:

```
<directive-one increment="increment" add="add"></directive-one>
```

Then you can invoke the function like this:

```
'<button ng-click="increment()()">Increment</button>' + 
'<button ng-click="add()(5)">Add</button>' +
```

I prefer this option over send the json object, i think that is cleaner.
https://plnkr.co/edit/Y3OJpMfcp5R05a8uk1av?p=preview